# PlanningPipeline::generatePlan generates discontinuous trajectories

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`joint_limits.yaml` seems correctly loaded, as indicated by the params

```
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/elbow_joint/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/elbow_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/elbow_joint/max_acceleration: 3.15
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/elbow_joint/max_velocity: 3.15
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_lift_joint/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_lift_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_lift_joint/max_acceleration: 2.16
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_lift_joint/max_velocity: 2.16
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_pan_joint/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_pan_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_pan_joint/max_acceleration: 2.16
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/shoulder_pan_joint/max_velocity: 2.16
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_1_joint/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_1_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_1_joint/max_acceleration: 3.2
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_1_joint/max_velocity: 3.2
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_2_joint/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_2_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_2_joint/max_acceleration: 3.2
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_2_joint/max_velocity: 3.2
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_3_joint/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_3_joint/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_3_joint/max_acceleration: 3.2
 * /robot_description_planning/joint_limits/wrist_3_joint/max_velocity: 3.2
```

Joint acceleration and velocity scaling was applied as follows:

motion_request.max_velocity_scaling_factor = 0.2;
motion_request.max_acceleration_scaling_factor = 0.2;

I create my planning pipeline as follows

```
ur10_planning_pipeline = std::make_shared<planning_pipeline::PlanningPipeline>
                         (planning_pipeline::PlanningPipeline(ur10_kinematic_model, nodeHandle, "planning_plugin", "request_adapters"));
```

And generate the plan as follows

```
planning_scene_monitor::LockedPlanningSceneRO lscene(ur10_planning_scene_monitor);
ur10_planning_pipeline -> generatePlan(lscene, motion_request, motion_response);
```

The resultant plan is inspected as follows

```
control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal joint_tjt_goal;

moveit_msgs::RobotTrajectory moveit_trajectory;
motion_response.trajectory_ -> getRobotTrajectoryMsg (moveit_trajectory);

joint_tjt_goal.trajectory = moveit_trajectory.joint_trajectory;

for (int j = 0; j < joint_tjt_goal.trajectory.points.size(); j++)
{
    ROS_INFO("----- Point[%d] -----", j);
    auto point = joint_tjt_goal.trajectory.points[j];

    for (int i = 0; i < point.positions.size(); i++)
    {
        ROS_INFO("positions[%d] = %f", i, point.positions[i]);
    }
}
```

Which shows large changes in position values (some seem like simple angle wrapping, but others seem entirely wrong)

e.g. Joint 1:

```
positions[1] = 0.009000  
positions[1] = 2.933868  
positions[1] = -5.707793 
positions[1] = 2.596154  
positions[1] = 2.542579  
positions[1] = 2.492396  
positions[1] = 2.444871  
positions[1] = 2.399476  
positions[1] = 2.355814  
positions[1] = 2.313621  
positions[1] = 2.272631  
positions[1] = 2.232677  
positions[1] = -3.901456 
positions[1] = 3.732475  
positions[1] = 2.308633  
positions[1] = 2.273000  
positions[1] = 2.237841  
positions[1] = 2.203072  
positions[1] = 2.168618
```

Joint 2:

```
positions[2] = 1.115631  
positions[2] = 1.171292  
positions[2] = 1.223828  
positions[2] = 1.393478  
positions[2] = -1.446829 
positions[2] = 1.497745  
positions[2] = 1.546420  
positions[2] = 1.593008  
positions[2] = 1.637637
```

Joint 3:

```
positions[3] = 0.000433  
positions[3] = 2.902240  
positions[3] = -2.494673 
positions[3] = 6.060256  
positions[3] = 6.040091  
positions[3] = 6.021166  
positions[3] = 6.003767  
positions[3] = 5.987991  
positions[3] = 5.973858  
positions[3] = 5.961364  
positions[3] = 5.950454  
positions[3] = 5.941130  
positions[3] = -3.799519 
positions[3] = 3.975718  
positions[3] = 2.457196  
positions[3] = 2.446128  
positions[3] = 2.436475  
positions[3] = 2.428223  
positions[3] = 2.421367  
positions[3] = 2.415900  
positions[3] = 2.411839  
positions[3] = -0.355148 
positions[3] = -0.348957 
positions[3] = -0.341480 
positions[3] = -0.332774
```

Joint 4:

```
positions[4] = -0.000017 
positions[4] = -2.839929 
positions[4] = -0.043669 
positions[4] = 2.785703  
positions[4] = 2.727666  
positions[4] = 2.669226
```

Joint 5:

```
positions[5] = -0.000027
positions[5] = 6.242936 
positions[5] = -3.628106
positions[5] = 3.020000 
positions[5] = 3.033377 
positions[5] = 3.043550 
positions[5] = 3.051558 
positions[5] = 3.058033 
positions[5] = 3.063395 
positions[5] = 3.067890 
positions[5] = 3.071729 
positions[5] = -3.208117
positions[5] = -0.063610
positions[5] = 6.222150 
positions[5] = 6.224444 
positions[5] = -0.056681
positions[5] = -0.054819
positions[5] = 6.230060 
positions[5] = 6.231608 
positions[5] = 6.233029 
positions[5] = 6.234341 
positions[5] = 3.093962 
positions[5] = 3.095087 
positions[5] = 3.096139 
positions[5] = 3.097118 
positions[5] = 3.098034 
positions[5] = 3.098889 
positions[5] = 3.099690 
positions[5] = 3.100436
```

Full output:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/6cfb15d494ffc4217a1de5eec492da6f

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353094/planningpipeline::generateplan-generates-discontinuous-trajectories/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A couple of related discussions can be found here:

- https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/562
- https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/541
- https://answers.ros.org/question/203662/planning-with-orientation-constraint-in-moveit/

In short, it is a known problem which seem to occur when there are orientation constraints (which I failed to mention in the problem...) and has no proper fix at the moment.  The current workaround is to use [`enforce_joint_model_state_space`](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/ompl_interface/ompl_interface_tutorial.html#enforce-planning-in-joint-space).

The idea of setting explicit joint jump limits was mentioned in the discussion but the interface for this is not available on OMPL side, thus cannot be implemented for the time being.

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2020-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0